# Searching Through Firebase for Data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data out of my firebase for a specific user via the realtime database. Whenever a user signs up and new piece is added to the `stripe_customers` piece of the database. How can I get the customer_id for each customer?

Current Customer - 

`var database = firebase.database();
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;`

Current Database Layout - [Database Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTamT.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand you clear, but it seems it is quite easy something like:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('stripe_customer/' + userId + '/customer_id');
dbRef.once('value', snapshot=> {
   if (snapshot.exists()){ 
       var custumerId = snapshot.val().customer_id; 
       _goAheadWithCustomerId(custumerId);
   } 
})
_goAheadWithCustomerId(c){
     console.log('Customer Id is :', c);
}
```

Comment: For some reason, that wasn't working. Any ideas? I fixed the spelling of customer and I am still getting an error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to console `snapshot.val().customer_id` or just `snapshot.val()` to see what you received. Also I made a mistake check : (ı forgat "/" before customer_id.. correct format is:  `database.ref('stripe_customer/' + userId + '/customer_id')`

Comment: After doing that, I am still getting a syntax error somewhere. Console is giving me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Comment: I edited the code above. Really sorry that I made syntax error and not defined correct database reference. Now should work.